# Редирект из поддомена на основной домен

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Добрый день существует проблема с поддоменами .
Существует сайт `site.com`  в htaccess есть редирект на `https://site.com`.
Возникает две ситуации

```
1. Ввод: test.site.com => Редирект на: https://site.com (это верно отрабатывает так и нужно)
2. Ввод:https://test.site.com => Редирект на: https://test.site.com (от этого необходимо избавиться)
```

Помогите разобраться с этим.
Сайт вертится на apache, php7

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.Aua$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.site.ua/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.site.ua/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Странное у вас какое-то требование номер 2. Но попробуйте заменить строки:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.Aua$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.site.ua/$1 [L,R=301]
```

на

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.ua$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.ua/$1 [L,R=301]
```

тогда любой домен отличный от `www.site.ua` должно перенаправлять на `https://www.site.ua/`.