# Настройка редиректа поддоменнов

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Необходимо сделать редирект таким образом:
     https://poddomen.site.com => https://site.com
Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730298/redirect-any-sub-domain-to-a-page-on-main-domain#answer-8732118

Comment: Дубликат предыдущего вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723202/186083

Answer (score 1):

Если через конфиги Apache2, то можно это сделать через виртуалхосты:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName poddomen.site.com
  RedirectPermanent / https://site.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

На примере был `https` поэтому ставим прослушивание 443 порта, если нужно `http` замените на `80`

Comment: спасибо каким образом сделать редирект с любого поддомена  так как при вводе https://test.site.com или чего то другого нужно сделать тоже самое

Comment: @shapik вам уже отвечали на вопрос по поводу редиректа со всех поддоменов, делается через RewriteCond, через виртуалхост вроде бы тоже можно через ServerAlias но тонкостей не помню, давно уже с ним не работал